# How Can I have the image displayed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Working on my first Angular project still, and now I need to start making the page(s) look a little better, and I'm wanting to add an image.

I know in Html it's just simply `<img src="*">` but angular doesn't actually load the image to the page.

My component file looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: ['.container-fluid{ border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px; padding: 
10px; border-radius: 20px;}','.qr-image{ width: 100px ;}'],
  template: `
    <h1> Regional Forum Report Registration</h1>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <form-area></form-area>
    </div>
    <div class="qr-code">
      <h3> Long Line? Scan this code to SignUp!</h3>
      <img class='qr-image' alt='Address for Signup Page' [src]="qrpath">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  this.qrpath = '/app/rf.png';
}
```

I've also looked through some other questions, and I have a few issues with some of them. First, why do they recommend using the square brackets around the `src` attribute? Second, why can't we just use `src="pathToImg.jpg"` ?

for further detail here is my folder structure:

[image: Project folder from Atom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use the square brackets when you want to use a variable.  ie `<img [src]="myVariableContainingPath" />`  If you want to hardcode the path, you can do it the normal way of `<img src="myPath.jpg" />` without the square brackets.

Square brackets = inserting a value from a variable.

Hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: it does, just enough to ask why it isn't working with just the `<img src="img.jpg">` call

Comment: Is the image in the location the browser is expecting?  What does the browser dev tools say?

Comment: derp. file path issues. Had to remember the path needed to be relative to the Index.html....